# Vulnerability using printf/scanf and %s

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Why does C tell me this is unsafe even when I try to give the correct input?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char id[8];

    printf("Your ID:");
    scanf("%s", id);

    printf("%s", id);

    return 0; 
}
```

I'm assuming because it could be exploited? How so?

Comment: Is internet search not working?

Comment: What if I put a 50 character string as the input? You only have an 8 byte buffer.

Comment: If someone types in more than 8 characters it will overwrite memory, with possibly disastrous consequences.

Comment: With the `char id[8]`  you're allocating a fixed amount of memory, but `scanf` doesn't know it.

Comment: Thank you all, I understand. I should've looked around!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf()` doesn't set any bounds on what it takes as input, so it's easy to overflow you `id[]` buffer.

Modern compilers will likely have stack smashing detection enabled, so if you compile via `gcc` without setting the `-fno-stack-protector` flag, the program will deliberately crash early rather than run with such a nasty bug going without being noticed.

You're best off using `fgets()` and then `sscanf()` or some other mechanism to parse the input so you can guarantee extra input is discarded.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to over running `id[]` with too much data, another vulnerability:
Not checking the input function's return value.

User could close `stdin` causing `scanf("%s", id)` to return `EOF` and not put anything in `id[]`.  The following `printf("%s", id);` then attempts to print an uninitialized buffer.

```
char id[8];
scanf("%s", id);  // Bad, return value not checked.
printf("%s", id);

// Better
if (1 == scanf("%7s", id)) {
  printf("%s", id);
}

// even better
if (fgets(id, sizeof id, stdin)) {
  id[strcspn(id, "\n")] = '\0'; // lop off potential \n
  printf("%s", id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`id` is 8 characters long buffer. `scanf("%s", id);` is not checking the length of the input string. So if the user is entering a string longer than 7 characters long (+1 for null-terminator), it will overflow the allocated buffer and break the program. If the string is crafted in a special way, it might allow a hacker to gain some priveleges, such as executing an arbitrary code.